# Detect Domain redirection from another domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect a domain example.com to a specific url otherdomain.com/test.

Usually what I would do is to host example.com on a server and add a redirect with PHP or .htaccess to otherdomain.com/test.

Right now example.com is already redirected from godaddy to otherdomain.com, so it is not hosted anywhere.

I was wondering if it was possible to detect on otherdomain.com that a redirect was being done from example.com. I have tried:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

This does not work because $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] gets populated when user clicks a link, I tried anyways.

Remember example.com is not hosted anywhere, it is being redirected automatically to otherdomain.com from godaddy domain manager.

Maybe is there a way to detect the redirect on PHP or htaccess?

Comment: What the answers below want to tell you is you have to redirect the url to something like `otherdomain.com/test?redirected-from=example.com` so you can utilize `redirected-from` parameter. An easy an best practice method is using some kind of analytics + `utm` parameters.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes I understand but domain is not hosted anywhere, redirect is done from godaddy, so I can not add parameters.

Comment: You can redirect the domain in godaddy to anywhere you want you can add parameters and everything....

Answer (score 1):

You can use google analytics service by adding tracking script into otherdomain.com

Comment: Interesting option, do you have an example about this?